Bash script that requires "yes" response to several queries before running command(s)
I'm trying to create a bash script that asks a series of questions posed in sequence, all of which need to be answered sequentially with the word "yes" before proceeding to the next question. After the final question is asked, a piece of data is solicited and that is read into a variable before two final commands are executed.
The script is complex enough that my rudimentary bash skills and a bit of internet sleuthing have so far not resulted in a solution. So I want to ask for some help here.
Below is dummy sample script containing a bit of pseudo-code mixed in with some valid commands that is meant to better convey what I'm aiming to do with this script.
#!/bin/sh
echo "This script will create a file for you and perhaps rename it. Press any key to continue." read anykey
logic here to wait intil a key is pressed, then move on to display the first question

echo "Would you like to create a file?" read ans1
if [ $ans1 == yes ]; then 
echo "Going to next question." #Logic here to proceed to next 
question
if [ $ans1 != yes ] echo "This question requires a 'yes' answer. Returning to question"
else logic here to re-pose question
fi

echo "Would you really like to create the file?" read ans2
if [ $ans2 == yes ]; then 
echo "Going to next question." #Logic here to proceed to next question
if [ $ans2 != yes ] echo "This question requires a 'yes' answer. Returning to question"
else logic here to re-pose question
fi

echo "Are you absolutely certain you'd like to create the file?" read ans3
if [ $ans3 == yes ]; then 
echo "Going to next question." #Logic here to proceed to next question
if [ $ans3 != yes ] echo "This question requires a 'yes' answer. Returning to question"
else logic here to re-pose question
fi

echo "Do you take seriously the responsibilities of creating this file?" read ans4
if [ $ans4 == yes ]; then 
echo "Going to next question." #Logic here to proceed to next question
if [ $ans4 != yes ] echo "This question requires a 'yes' answer. Returning to question"
else logic here to re-pose question
fi

echo "Do you make a firm commitment to not frivolously deleting this file?" read ans5
if [ $ans5 == yes ]; then 
echo "Going to next item." #Logic here to proceed to next item
if [ $ans5 != yes ] echo "This question requires a 'yes' answer. Returning to question"
else logic here to re-pose question
fi

echo "Ok, if you insist on doing this please enter a name for the file:" read filename

echo "Creating file $filename"

touch $filename

echo "Your choice of file names is judged inadequate. Renaming file."

mv $filename adequate-filename

echo "Congratulations, you have successfully created a file. Exiting"

done

I can't determine whether, for example, while loops or until loops might be applicable here. Input on this task will be appreciated. Thanks
LATER EDIT: Here's what I came up with using a function (as was suggested by Marcus)--lots of credit to AI:
#!/bin/bash 
read -n1 -s -r -p "This script will create a file for you and perhaps rename it. Press any key to continue."
echo
echo
# Function to ask yes-only questions 
ask_question() 
{ 
    while true; 
    do 
        read -p "$1 (yes only): " answer 
        if [[ "$answer" == "yes" ]]; then break 
        else 
            echo "Please answer yes." 
        fi 
    done 
} 
# Ask 5 yes-only questions 
ask_question "Would you like to create a file?" 
ask_question "Would you really like to create the file?" 
ask_question "Are you absolutely certain you'd like to create the file?" 
ask_question "Do you take seriously the responsibilities of creating this file?" 
ask_question "Do you make a firm commitment to not frivolously deleting this file?" 
echo
read -p "Ok, if you insist on doing this please enter a name for the file: " filename
sleep 1 && touch $filename
sleep 2
echo "Your choice of file names is judged inadequate. Renaming file."
mv $filename $(date +%m-%d-%y)-$filename
echo "Congratulations, you have successfully created a file."
# Final question 
read -p "Are you ready to exit? (yes/no): " ready_answer 
# Check if the user is ready 
if [[ "$ready_answer" == "yes" ]]; then 
    echo "Your new file has been saved as $(ls $(date +%m-%d-%y)-$filename)"
else 
    echo "You are not ready." 
fi

Any improvements/corrections needed? This is a while loop running inside a function, right?

Hi! Quite honestly, this code is very repetitive (because the problem is very repetitive), and I'd probably just write one function that takes the question to ask as argument, and succeeds after "yes" has been replied. (also, I'm sure you're 100% aware of this, but the way you approach this means terrible user experience, and psychologically, you can be almost certain that everyone stops reading your questions after the third time they typed "yes", the latest, so probably quite the opposite of what you mean to achieve.)

Thanks for the tip Marcus. I'll look into functions, something I have very little experience with. Though I may have added one or two to my .bashrc.

If switching to zsh is an option, then you can use its read -q to ask yes/no questions

functions and/or zsh are both great directions to go! Also, there's absolutely no reason this must be a shell script. If you, for example, are already versed in Python, I'd write it in Python. Makes for easier to write and read code ;) and if you replace the #!/bin/sh with #!/usr/bin/env python3, then you get the same executability, but would have to write Python instead of bash script.

I've written a few fairly simplistic bash scripts in my time but know next to nothing about python. So that's defintiely a path of more resistance, even if it might be the better option for this task. As for zsh, I've only used it when booted into some live distro (system rescure cd, if memory serves). Thanks.

I expect the questions here are just for the sake of example, but I just want to note that a question like "Would you really like to create the file?" isn't very informative, it doesn't say what file would be created, or if creating it would involve overwriting an earlier file (which e.g. cmd > file or that mv foo file would happily do). Instead, you might want to just consider saying what you're going to do, e.g. "Creating file 'foo.txt', ok? (Y/n)". And creating the file with means that don't clobber an existing file, unless you specifically asked about that, too.

or, you know, just don't have the program ask for confirmation for what the user asked to do to begin with, and instead just get on with the job. :) There are ways of actually forcing the user to pay attention, but those are best left for the rare cases where a mistake can cause a huge mess, like making your whole system unusable by removing essential packages, or writing garbage on a write-once media, or bricking some device by screwing up the bootloader, or things like that.

As for the "terrible user experience" I'm the only user that will ever be exposed to this script. I'm trying to automate with it a somewhat complex back-up routine I've developed: the repetitiveness is to help me recall elements of the routine that I tend to forget in the 6-month to 1-year intervals between back-ups. So the real script is not simply touching a file, but is instead producing a .tar.gz file containing the back-up. That said, the dummy script here provided is fairly faithful to the flow of the actual back-up script--though that one has 11 initial questions instead of 5.

@MJiller, probably best would be to arrange the process so that it's hard to impossible to miss steps. If there's anything that can be done programmatically, have the script do it automatically. If there's anything that can't be done programmatically, but can be verified programmatically, have the script do that. (The program can't make you pick the correct tape from the shelf, but if the tapes have machine-readable ids, the program can check you entered the correct tape. But if that can't be done, then, yes, this might well be a case where you need to force the user to pay attention.)

There won't be a risk of clobbering any files in the real, non-dummy script, because I am including today's date in the file name in that one.

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Maybe you want to protect from the lazy user just piping in yes | ./yourscript with `[ -t 0 ]'.

Also, maybe post the solution that you edited into your question as a proper answer to your question seeing as it seems to resolve it.

You probably should put all your variable expansions inside "" to protect against whitespace, and assign $(date +%m-%d-%y)-$filename to a variable before use to avoid surprises if you run the script close to midnight.

Instead of repeating the same code to ask 5 questions, just read them in a loop or read them into an array and then loop through the array contents, e.g. untested:
readarray -t question << 'EOF'
Would you like to create a file? 
Would you really like to create the file? 
Are you absolutely certain you'd like to create the file? 
Do you take seriously the responsibilities of creating this file? 
Do you make a firm commitment to not frivolously deleting this file?
EOF

for question in "${questions[@]}"; do
    answer=''
    response=''
    while [[ "$answer" != "yes" ]]; do
        printf '%s' "$response" >&2
        response=$'Please answer yes.\n' 
        IFS= read -r -p "$question (yes only): " answer
    fi
done


This addresses only part of your problems, but ....
while true .... loops are so ugly and unstructured.  Just don't.
# Function to ask yes-only questions
ask_question()
{
    local answer  # leaves answer unset
    while [[ "$answer" != "yes" ]]
    do
        [[ "${answer+null}" ]] && echo "Please answer yes."
        read -p "$1 (yes only): " answer
    done
}

Fewer lines of code to boot.
The [[ "${answer+null}" ]] && echo bit ensures that the message is echoed if a previous answer has been received, but doesn't print it the first time through (because answer is unset).
